Docker Container Networking Issue on Unifi CloudKey Gen 2: Fails Without --net host
I have an old Unifi CloudKey Gen 2 that I have repurposed as just a linux box. It's very fast and PoE so it's the perfect SBC for any project. I installed docker and it will run containers, BUT when I try to run a container that requires network, it will not run with the following error UNLESS I specify --net host, which no longer allows me to port forward from the container -> host.
If I disable nginx, which runs the Unifi admin interface and is using port 80/443, the docker container runs fine with --net host.
Having a hard time finding any info on this error. Any ideas?
docker info output:
root@DockerPen:~# docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    27.3.1
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.17.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.29.7
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 6
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 5
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 27.3.1
 Storage Driver: vfs
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc io.containerd.runc.v2
Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 57f17b0a6295a39009d861b89e3b3b87b005ca27
 runc version: v1.1.14-0-g2c9f560
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
 Kernel Version: 3.18.44-ui-qcom
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 1.929GiB
 Name: DockerPen
 ID: e9bb9d23-8563-4003-96f4-7b1ca0cacf2f
 Docker Root Dir: /srv/var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled

running a docker container without the --net host option: <-- This is the issue I am trying to solve.
root@DockerPen:~# docker run -d -p 8080:80 httpd
497c3faf43c3c691b6231bf6973282c0c3c0f34f90bd8ea7c783e6d59051bf34
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: failed to set gateway while updating gateway: route for the gateway 172.17.0.1 could not be found: decoding failed: buffer too small (4 bytes): unknown.

Even without a container that requires network, this error persists:
root@DockerPen:~# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: failed to set gateway while updating gateway: route for the gateway 172.17.0.1 could not be found: decoding failed: buffer too small (4 bytes): unknown.

The system WILL run the docker container with the --net host option however, for http specifically, port 80 is taken by the Unifi admin web interface, so it fails for that reason:
root@DockerPen:~# docker run -d --net host httpd
61a6dd20b2b8276b040b4c7b7ee72c88e48b9aadcb51a279607bba76264e15cd
root@DockerPen:~# docker logs 61
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Container that does not require network now runs fine with --net host option:
root@DockerPen:~# docker run --net host hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (arm64v8)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall docker. Also, for context, docker did set up a network inetface:
root@DockerPen:~# ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:7ff:fec6:fd56  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:07:c6:fd:56  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17  bytes 1005 (1005.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Also for context, an output of network inspect bridge:
root@DockerPen:~# docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "374161cbed7e81b64f1beb9c8864de46f7b2b122044e87bfa34e45e3d9e5a0a8",
        "Created": "2024-11-25T20:02:23.112345724-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]

Also, also.. If I disable nginx, which runs the Unifi admin interface and is using port 80/443, the docker container runs fine with --net host... It's got to be something simple I'm missing.

What distro are you using?

The device is running Debian 10 Buster with a custom Kernel : Linux version 3.18.44-ui-qcom (bdd@builder) (gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) ) #1 SMP Mon Sep 23 17:27:11 CST 2024

Oh it's just using reconfigured stock firmware? That's cool. I don't really have much to go on, I thought i'd look into the firmware you were using, my only idea is that ubiquiti's kernel might be missing something. I assume you've installed docker using the official sources? Has anyone else been able to run docker on one of these devices?

Not that I have found confirming but yes, both with apt install and through instructions from docker directly. It’s very cool tech, super quick but I too suspect something in the custom kernel is killing the project. Sad.

Strangely enough, uninstalling and re-installing fixed the issue.
I had it tracked down to a firewall and/or routing issue but all of the routes were proper. I uninstalled it from reinstalled it using apt and now everything works.
